# Split AND sort list Jinja/Pelican

Tags: python, jinja2, pelican

I am using Pelican to generate a static blog. I have a links page with three columns filled from a central list. I would like the links to be **(a)** sorted alphabetically and then **(b)** split into three. Currently I can do either **(a)** or **(b)** but not both at the same time.

**(a)** sorted alphabetically (this produces three identical columns sorted alphabetically):

```html
{% for name, link in LINKS|sort %}
<li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}            
</div>
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
{% for name, link in LINKS|sort %}
<li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
{% for name, link in LINKS|sort %}
<li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

**(b)** split into three parts (this splits the unsorted list into three parts):

```html
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
{% for name, link in LINKS[0:10] %}
<li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}            
</div>
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
{% for name, link in LINKS[11:20] %}
<li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
{% for name, link in LINKS[21:30] %}
<li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
            </div>
```

To clarify. I wish to sort alphabetically LINKS and then split into three equal parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`slice()`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#slice) filter to group your sorted links into 3 separate groups; you can then nest the loops:

```html
{% for column in LINKS|sort|slice(3) %}
<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
    {% for name, link in column %}
    <li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> template = Template('''
... {% for column in LINKS|sort|slice(3) %}
... <div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">
...     {% for name, link in column %}
...     <li><a href="{{ link }}">{{ name }}</a></li>
...     {% endfor %}
... </div>
... {% endfor %}
... ''')
>>> links = [
...     ('Foo', 'link/to/foo'),
...     ('Bar', 'link/to/bar'),
...     ('Spam', 'link/to/spam'),
...     ('Ham', 'link/to/ham'),
...     ('Eggs', 'link/to/eggs'),
... ]
>>> print template.render(LINKS=links)


<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">

    <li><a href="link/to/bar">Bar</a></li>

    <li><a href="link/to/eggs">Eggs</a></li>

</div>

<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">

    <li><a href="link/to/foo">Foo</a></li>

    <li><a href="link/to/ham">Ham</a></li>

</div>

<div class="l-box pure-u-1-3">

    <li><a href="link/to/spam">Spam</a></li>

</div>
```

Comment: I did try slice lots of times. It didn't seem to work for me the way I was using it! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wow, that worked better than I could have hoped. Thanks again!